# Canonical term for something that can only occur once? Something that can occur multiple times?

Tags: terminology

I'm really anal about what I name my classes, and I need an adjective for both something that is only allowed to happen once, as well as something that is allowed to happen multiple times.

examples:

- *wordthatmeansitcanonlyhappenonce*Trigger
- *wordthatmeansitcanhappenmultipletimes*Trigger

Comment: lol thanks for the edit Hank... what the heck is "Caconical"??

Comment: Probably belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OneShotTrigger and RecurringTrigger

Comment: especially like the 'Recurring' in that.

Comment: +1 for Recurring, not so crazy about "OneShot" - maybe I'll just use "NonRecurring"

Comment: "OneShotTrigger" sounds pretty good to me. Perhaps "ResetTrigger" instead of "RecurringTrigger"?

Answer (score 2):

For one time: [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce).

Comment: in the UK the first thing that springs to mind for "nonce" is "sex offender" :)

Comment: @Paul: I guess I'm sheltered: never heard of that before ;)

Comment: You might go with Trigger and NonceTrigger. Don't see why they both need special names. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OneShotTrigger
RepeatableTrigger

Answer (score 1):

How about

- SingularTrigger
- PluralTrigger

Also, I don't think this is exactly what you're getting at, but this may be related to [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent).

Answer (score 1):

With tongue ever so slightly in cheek, how about:

- BirthTrigger - you only get born once.
- BirthdayTrigger - but you can have lots of birthdays

Answer (score 1):

singleTrigger
multiTrigger

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 'OneTime' for the single shot, and nothing particular for the multiple case.
It's not really canonical though...

Answer (score 0):

onceTrigger, manyTrigger

oneTrigger, manyTrigger

Also, sometimes I just don't name one (once or many) and name the other (once or many) to make it stand out.  Maybe you could just put an 's' on the end of one and not the other.

Comment: I ry to distinguish between plurals and singlular a lot in my methods. E.g. createPost() and fetchPosts(...)

Answer (score 0):

I just use "OneTime." Maybe it's a poker thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could call them [WyclefJeanTrigger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vl8DEwRZUK0) and [TimMcGrawTrigger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=temaoKXSVxw). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Singular or Once

Answer (score 0):

SingleShot and Repeating are commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

MonochronicTrigger
PolychronicTrigger

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have a suggestion not yet mention.

As a pair

```
UnrepeatableTrigger
RepeatableTrigger
```

work well.

Though, much like Microsoft, when using the registry to ensure that things happen only once on startup, they use the term RunOnce.

So instantly, I would recognize

```
RunOnceTrigger
```

as being something more maintainable and clear than

```
OnceTrigger
```

`OneShotTrigger` almost sounds desperate "we've only got one shot at this and if it fails we're up the creek without a paddle".

`Monochronic and Polychronic` do not seem to be relevant, as mentioned here.

> Monochronic and polychronic time
>   systems are two terms used to refer to
>   time and its influence on society.
>
> monochronic time
>   system means that things are done one
>   at a time and time is segmented into
>   precise, small units.

Here are some other adjectives.. I particularly like `Unrepeatable` just beause it sounds like you're talking about a family taboo, or Voldermort.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/american/Happening-only-once